# model.fit() stopping halfway on 1 epoch using tensorflow-directml. What to do?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, amd-processor

Currently using tensorflow-directml as I am training a model on AMD (RX 580). The problem is, upon `model.fit()` it seems to be stuck at epoch 1 with no progress. Here's my code and error:

```
with tensorflow.device('/device:GPU:0'):
start = perf_counter()
history = model.fit(n_train_ds,
                    epochs=15,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(n_train_ds),
                    validation_data=n_test_ds,
                    validation_steps=len(n_test_ds),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, early_stop],
                    verbose=1,
                    class_weight=n_class_weights)
end = perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

Error:

> Epoch 1/15
> WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function..train_function at 0x000002063B21A840> and will run it as-is.
> Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
> Cause: 'arguments' object has no attribute 'posonlyargs'
> To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
> WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function..train_function at 0x000002063B21A840> and will run it as-is.
> Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
> Cause: 'arguments' object has no attribute 'posonlyargs'
> To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert

Additional info from command prompt:
[image: Info]

Update: I tried adding some parameters and it is now moving but it stops halfway the first epoch. Not sure if I encounter internal runtime error as script is still running.

> 41/758 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:15 - loss: 1.5688 - accuracy: 0.3628

Comment: Well, it says `Please report this to the TensorFlow team. [..]`. Did you do that?

Comment: Not yet because I think there might be workaround for this. I did manage to get the epoch running but it seem to crash/ midway. Currently stuck at 55/798 on the first epoch with ETA 11:15. Still waiting for any workaround :/